# MySQL group by one column and bind/join another column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can I group results by one column but loop through the results of another column?

Example I have a database table named `albums_sold` formed by:

```
id | buyer_email | albums_id
```

I want to do something similar to:

```
"SELECT buyer_email, albums_id FROM albums_sold GROUP BY buyer_email"
```

I want to group the results by `buyer_email` but get all the values from `albums_id` of each `buyer_email` in the loop.

Comment: Use `GROUP_CONCAT(albums_id)`  in your query.

Comment: @Mihai can you show me an example please

Comment: SELECT buyer_email, GROUP_CONCAT(albums_id) FROM albums_sold GROUP BY buyer_email

Comment: Question: Is it possible though to group by buyer_email then loop through the values of albums_id of that buyer_email, something like a subquery ?

Comment: I dont understand,if you group by something the values are collapsed as it were.What do you mean loop through?What are you trying to do?

Comment: @mihai Like doing the first query "SELECT buyer_email FROM albums_sold GROUP BY buyer_email" Then loop through buyers emails and do a second query "SELECT albums_id FROM buyer_email WHERE buyer_email = 'current buyer_email'" somethig  link this but in 1 single query ? Possible ?

Comment: Edit your question with some sample data and desired results.

Comment: You could JOIN with a subquery but i dont see the point: `your query JOIN (subquery) as x on x.buyer_email =albums_sold.buyer_email`